# Unparseable Date Exception in Java using Json Data

Tags: java

I am new to java. While trying to transform the date format I get an exception:unparseable date and don't know how to fix this problem. Date is in this format `"date":"2021-01-12"`.  My Entity class looks like this.

What I was trying to do is the following:

```
private String id;
private Date date ;       
        
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

and My Business Class is:

```
String dataoffer = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("D:\\rates.json"))) {
            String sCurrentLine;
    
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataoffer += sCurrentLine;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        Gson gsondataoffer = new GsonBuilder().create();
            
        CurrencyEntity wrapperData = gsondataoffer.fromJson(dataoffer, CurrencyEntity.class);
        System.out.println(wrapperData);
```

Does anyone know how to convert the example date

Comment: Which version of `GSON` are you using and of which type is the `Date`? `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

I tested your issue with various versions of the GSON library (and the `java.util.Date` class) and it turned out to work from `GSON 2.5`.

According to their release notes they say the following:

> Improved Date Deserialization by accepting many date formats

The full release notes you can find [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-25).

So the simplest way to fix your issue is to simply upgrade the version of the GSON library you use.

---

**Long answer**

The issue is that the `DateFormat` like it's specified in your JSON is not recognized by the GSON library (in the versions prior to 2.5).

Alternative ways to fix the issue by keeping the current version of GSON you currently have is:

1. To specify the alternate `DateFormat` in the `GSONBuilder` while constructing the GSON object:

   `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").create();`
2. To specify a custom *Date-Deserializer* like the following:

   `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, dateDeserializer).create();`

The full code for to specify the *Date-Deserializer* looks like this (note moving it in a separate class and will make the code more readable and result in a leaner code base. Here it's inline to show as less code as possible, but display the principle and list the needed imports.):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JsonDeserializer<Date> dateDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                String date = json.getAsString();

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

                try {
                    return formatter.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.err.println("Failed to parse Date due to: " + e.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, dateDeserializer).create();

        Entity fromJson = gson.fromJson(JsonData.json, Entity.class); // Entity is the entity class in same package as
                                                                        // Driver; JsonData is holding the JSON string
                                                                        // with the date which you have in a file (also
                                                                        // in same package as Driver)
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(fromJson));
    }
}
```

**Concluding notes**

- Also remember to implement and provide a similar *Date-Serializer* to have a consistent mapping from Json and to Json
- When working with `Dates` in real world applications, you might need to consider working with different TimeZones to process dates in an accurate way
- The `java.util.Date` is actually the old implementation of Java to work with Dates. From Java 8 and above you might consider to work with the new implementations from the `java.time.*` package like `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.time.LocalDate`